# Custom context menu in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, contextmenu, qtreeview

I currently have this dialog widget:

```
class TaskTypeTreeEditor(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._view = QTreeView()
        self._view.setItemDelegate(TaskTypeNameDelegate())
        self._view.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self._view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self._open_menu)

        self._refresh()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self._view)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle(_('Admin.editTaskType'))

    def _open_menu(self, position):
        indexes = self._view.selectedIndexes()
        if len(indexes) == 0:
            return

        menu = QMenu()
        ids = [index.internalPointer().type_id for index in indexes]

        if len(indexes) == 1:
            NewTypeAction(ids[0], self._refresh, menu)

        DeleteTypeAction(ids, self._refresh, menu)

        menu.exec_(self._view.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    def _refresh(self):
        model = TaskTypeTreeModel()
        self._view.setModel(model)
        self._view.expandAll()
```

This was based on another design from the Python wiki. Assuming `NewTypeAction` and `DeleteTypeAction` are subclasses of `QAction` and their constructors appropriately call `QAction.__init__` with the parent of `menu`, why when I right click in my view doesn't a menu appear?

Comment: Educated guess: because `indexes` is empty?

Comment: @ekhumoro Nope. I did a quick test, and it is continuing to execute. Looks like it is actually making a blank menu despite me passing the parent when creating the action. I can tell, because my next click is ignored after right clicking; I didn't notice that before.

Comment: Well, since no one else can see the relevant code, I suppose it's up to you to do the rest of the debugging ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. I forgot to call `menu.addAction` for both of my new actions.